# Cycle forward and backward through two arrays in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, iframe, cycle

This script is used to switch out content in two separate iframes. Each has it's own specific content, that does need to be in sync. I originally created it to only cycle forward on any keyup trigger. It worked fine. Then I was asked to cycle backward on a "back" button event.

It cycles, but now on the backward cycle, the content in the iframes gets out of sync, and the cycle isn't iterative, but seemingly random, depending on where in the forward cycle you are, jumping between iFrames.

The code works in the forward cycle, and I don't want to break that.

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var locations = ["Assets/Assets0.html", "Assets/Assets1.html", "Assets/Assets2.html", "Assets/Assets3.html"];
    var details = ["Details1/Details0.html", "Details1/Details1.html", "Details1/Details2.html", "Details1/Details3.html"];
    var len = locations.length;
    var len2 = details.length;
    var iframe = $('#Results');
    var iframe2 = $('#Description');
    var i = 0;
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
        // handle delete key
        if (event.keyCode == 8) {
            $(iframe).attr('src', locations[--i % len]);
            $(iframe2).attr('src', details[-i % len2]);

        // all other keys
        } else  {
            $(iframe).attr('src', locations[++i % len]);
            $(iframe2).attr('src', details[+i % len2]);
          }
        });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: OK, got the answer: Array stays the same, pulled variable out on it's own, used switch function.     `$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (e) {
 switch (e.keyCode) {
 case 8: // delete
 if (i > 0) { 
  i--;
 } else {
  i = locations.length - 1;
 }
 break;
 default:
  if (i < locations.length - 1) {
   i++;
 } else {
  i = 0;
 }
 break;
 }
  $('#Results').attr('src', locations[i]);
  $('#Description').attr('src', details[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Modulo with negative numbers is something weird... just try it out:

You expect, for example, `-1 % 3` to give you 3 (last element) while it is actually `2`.

My suggestion is to put an `if` around the "going back" code to cope with `i == 0`.